# CMake doesn't find boost

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, cmake

Windows 7. 64bit. CMake 2.8.10.

Steps:

- download boost: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.51.0/
- put it to **C:\work\lib\boost_1_51_0-MT**
- open "Start->All Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010->Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)"
- command:

```
cd C:\work\lib\boost_1_51_0-MT
bootstrap.bat
bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 --variant=release --build-type=complete -j 4 --with-regex --with-test --with-filesystem --with-date_time --with-random --with-system --with-thread --with-program_options --with-chrono --with-math stage link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static
```

- command:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=C:\work\lib\boost_1_51_0-MT
cmake M:\project

  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.51.0

  Boost include path: C:/work/lib/boost_1_51_0-MT

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_system
          boost_thread
          boost_random
          boost_chrono

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

M:\project\CMakeLists.txt contains: (i need to link boost statically)

```
...
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS ON)
set(USE_STATIC_BOOST ON)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)

find_package(Boost 1.48.0 COMPONENTS system thread random chrono REQUIRED)
...
```

This CMakeLists.txt is old and works on other boost installations (done by me and not me in past, but the recepies is lost).

**Solved**

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

...now CMake finds boost libraries! Although my "set(USE_STATIC_BOOST ON)" must have the same effect, but it doesnt...

Comment: It would probably make sense to post the "Solved" part as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

**Solved**

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

...now CMake finds boost libraries! Although my CMakeLists.txt has `set(USE_STATIC_BOOST ON)` which must have the same effect, but it doesnt...

To use `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)` you need to add:

```
if( WIN32 )
  # Needed for boost to turn off autolinking for dynamic linking
  add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
endif()
```

See more at:
[Linking boost library with Boost_USE_STATIC_LIB OFF on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887680/linking-boost-library-with-boost-use-static-lib-off-on-windows)