# Single threaded application with Boost and CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

*I'm writing a single threaded application. I use CMake to compile it. My application is being written in C++ using Boost. When run 'make' linking of my application fails with following error message:*

```
Linking CXX executable whisk
cd <project>/build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/driver_simdag.cpp.o CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/whisk.cpp.o CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/driver_miror.cpp.o CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/driver.cpp.o CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/main.cpp.o  -o whisk -rdynamic -lboost_program_options 
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/whisk.dir/whisk.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**This is the error itself:**

```
 undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

**My CMakeLists.txt from the src directory is following:**

```
file(GLOB whisk_SRC "[a-zA-Z]*.cpp")
add_executable(whisk ${whisk_SRC})

FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.40 COMPONENTS program_options log REQUIRED )
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      OFF)
# set_property(TARGET whisk PROPERTY Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

set_property(TARGET whisk PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET whisk PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

target_link_libraries(whisk ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})

install(TARGETS whisk DESTINATION bin)
```

**How do I tell CMake and Boost that I do not pthreads at all and I want single threaded version to be compiled?**

Comment: How is CMake relevant here and can you compile successfully from the commandline? Is your Boost library perhaps not available in a single-threaded version (use `ldd` to find dependencies)? Also, what gains do you expect from a single-threaded version?

Comment: Try building boost with `threading=single`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I turned out that I have the same problem, when I compile from the command line. So, probably you're right cmake could be irrelevant here. I want single-threaded version, because I'm sure that I will not need thread safety, because my application is always going to be single threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FindBoost](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindBoost.html) documentation page, you need to use

Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED  - Set to OFF to use the non-multithreaded
                           libraries ('mt' tag).  Default is ON.

Set this before calling `find_package(Boost)`. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902261/3154588) to [Linking boost library with Boost_USE_STATIC_LIB OFF on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887680/linking-boost-library-with-boost-use-static-lib-off-on-windows) I show details on how I have built against boost using cmake. The relevant part to answer your question is

```
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
find_package( Boost 1.57.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED )
```

When using makefiles, I often find it helpful to use `make VERBOSE=1` to see exactly what commands the make system is invoking.